# Can I use a US IP address to more easily get Google AdSense approval?

Tags: google-adsense, ip-address, country-specific

I m from Bangladesh. I need to make new blogger website. A few of my friends tried, but didn't get Google AdSense approval yet, even though they are good bloggers.

I'm thinking that it will be easier to get approval if I make blog to using  US IP  address or if my friend who lives in the USA creates the blog for me then hands it over after few weeks.  Would this have any benefits for Google AdSense approval?

Does Google Adsense have any country based approval policies?

Comment: What details would you be putting in for payment?  Do you have a US bank account?